# Using and call bookamrk in activities using rehosted

Tags: workflow-foundation-4, bookmarks

I'm using WF, I res-hosted the designer, and everything is fine till i need in my custom activities to wait a value when workflow is running, that what i made using BOOKMARK. i tried bookmark in ConsoleApplication and its work.
the following code i used in the main class in the  ConsoleApplication:

```
AutoResetEvent syncEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false);
wa.Completed = delegate(WorkflowApplicationCompletedEventArgs r)
{
    syncEvent.Set();
};

wa.Run();
wa.ResumeBookmark("bookmarkName", Console.ReadLine());

syncEvent.WaitOne();
```

but here in my rehosted project, i need to call many workflows. not only 1. and I can't specify it before runtime.
for this method:

```
wa.ResumeBookmark("bookmarkName", Console.ReadLine());
```

1st argument: bookmarks' names, i tried and i found i can name all bookmarks the same name.
About the 2nd argument, how can I pass the value for each workflow, and some workflows have more than 1 bookmark.
I have to read the value from many places, asp.net pages, DB and others.
Im sure there is something like these in WF 4.0, but i didnt find it. can u help me please :)
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep track of each workflow's [Id](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activities.workflowapplication.id.aspx), and record that Id when a bookmark is created.  Once you wish to return to the workflow, you can search for the one with the matching Id and then resume your bookmark.

Comment: Thank you. and how is that(record the ID and Resume the specific )? do you have any link or something else like a full example ?

Comment: @Sofy: When the [PersistableIdle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activities.workflowapplication.persistableidle.aspx) callback is called, it takes an instance of [WorkflowApplicationIdleEventArgs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activities.workflowapplicationidleeventargs.aspx) which contains not only the bookmarks created but also the instance Id of the workflow.  Associate the id with the bookmarks, so that when you come back and wish to persist your bookmarks you will be able to find the particular instance of the workflow.

Comment: you mean like the example of bookmark here http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WF/WF4Extensions.aspx ? even it throws an exception

Comment: @Sofy: Now you've got an exception.  Nothing about that in the original question.

Comment: Did u had a look on it? Is it the right 1? And the exception throws at InstanceView view = store.Execute(handle, new CreateWorkflowOwnerCommand(), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));

Comment: Ok, what about the object value? Its different in each bookmark.

Comment: @Sofy: You've got a lot of issues that can't be solved here.  You need to break apart what you're trying to do into the smallest parts and work on them one at a time.  Stop looking at the big picture and start working on the individual parts.  You can ask questions about each part.  Or hire someone who knows how to do it.

Comment: I'm asking about the same method, how can I pass the 2nd argument for all workflows!! Anyway, thank you.